# transaction malleability "attack" vectors

Tags: transaction-malleability

are any of the following transaction malleability "attack" vectors currently feasible?

alter scriptsig from:

```
OP_PUSHDATA <sig> OP_PUSHDATA <pubkey>
```

to one of:

```
1) OP_1 OP_SHA1 OP_DROP OP_PUSHDATA <sig> OP_PUSHDATA <pubkey>
2) OP_PUSHDATA <sig> OP_PUSHDATA <pubkey> OP_1 OP_SHA1 OP_DROP
3) OP_PUSHDATA <sig> OP_PUSHDATA <pubkey> OP_NOP
```

so that the corresponding scriptpubkey still evaluates to true:

```
OP_DUP OP_HASH160 OP_PUSHDATA <address> OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG
```

i can't tell if this is handled by point 6 in [bip 62](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0062.mediawiki) or not:

> 6. **Superfluous scriptSig operations** Adding extra data pushes at the start of scripts, which are not consumed by the corresponding
>      scriptPubKey, is also a source of malleability.

[judging by the code](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/main.cpp#L693-L701) it looks like it has been taken care of, but my c++ knowledge is not great...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Point (6) does not eliminate this source of malleability. Rather, point (2) of BIP62 disallows all three modifications you suggested. BIP62 describes the problem:

> **Non-push operations in scriptSig** Any sequence of script operations in scriptSig that results in the intended data pushes, but is not just a push of that data, results in an alternative transaction with the same validity.

And the proposed solution:

> **Non-push operations in scriptSig** Only data pushes are allowed in scriptSig. Evaluating any other operation makes the script evaluate to false. See reference: Push operators.

Comment: one last one - how about a doubling the scriptsig content:`OP_PUSHDATA <sig> OP_PUSHDATA <pubkey> OP_PUSHDATA <sig> OP_PUSHDATA <pubkey>` - i think this would still evaluate to true, right?

Comment: @mulllhausen Point (6) prevents against that. It would evaluate to true with a typical transaction, but it would be a non-standard and not relayed. For transactions in which bip62 goes into effect, it would evaluate to false, though.